# Laravel Passport doesn't generate tokens

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel as back-end for my ionic application, and Laravel Passport for authentication. When I try to call `createToken()` of `Auth` it shows, `Call to undefined method`

**Login.ts**:

```
login(event){
        let dataJSON;
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('email',event.target[0].value)
        formData.append('password',event.target[1].value)
        this.http.post(ENV.BASE_URL+'/auth', formData)
        .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data);

            dataJSON = data;
        }, (error) => {
            console.log("Error!", error);
        });
        return false;
    }
```

**UserController.php**:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller{
    public function auth(Request $request){
        $params = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $username = $params['email'];
        $password = $params['password'];
        if(\Auth::attempt(['email' => $username, 'password' => $password])){
            $token = \Auth::user()->createToken('Token'); //Throws Error here
            return response()->json(['token'=>$token]);
        }
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid username or Password']);
    }
}
```

**Error Log**:
When I tested using Postman, it throws following error

`Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser::createToken() in file
D:\PsResources\DroidWorkspace\ZiPay\ZipServer\app\Http\Controllers\UserController.php on line 16
Stack trace:
  1. Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError-&gt;() D:\PsResources\DroidWorkspace\ZiPay\ZipServer\app\Http\Controllers\UserController.php:16`

**auth.php**

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'table' => 'users',
    ],
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'users',
     ],
],
```

**user.php**

```
namespace App;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird,I deleted whole project and started fresh one, everything works fine.

Answer (score 11):

The issue for me was that the User model used closure utilized which is wrong because I'm using passport tokens:

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
```

I replaced my import with the correct one:

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
```

Comment: thank you bro this is what I was locked in

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
\Auth::user()->createToken('Token')->accessToken;
```

**Update:**

Check the following:

1. did you add this 'Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,' in app.php providers array?
2. did you change api->driver to 'passport' in auth.php in guards array?

[image: Config/App.php]

[image: Config/Auth.php]

Comment: I have added both, still the error exist. Actually when i call `createToken()` it should be calling from `HasApiToken` class, but in error it shows, it's trying to access from `Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser`

Comment: this might fix the problem, do not use \Auth::user()->createToken('Token')->accessToken(); use this : $user = User::where('email',$email)->where('password',$password)->firstOrFail(); then after fetching the user model generate a token like this , $token = $user->createToken('token')->accessToken();

Comment: Sorry. This doesn't help too. It throws Error 404. And when i try to fetch the authenticated user details by `$user = \Auth::user();` , it returns empty string.

Comment: did you put these values $username, $password in the place of email and password? if you did then it should work 100% because its whole new piece of code it does not needs any auth check middleware you simply checking a user and fetching if valid , i think theres a problem in the request. try setting $username and $password variable to correct value like $username = 'correct username' do not pick the value from the request if it works then there is something wrong in your request method

Comment: The `Auth:attempt()` part works perfectly, if I pass invalid credential, it returns 'invalid credential` to client, I don't know why `Auth::user()` not fetching details of current user

Comment: I think I should go back to JWT. It was way easier than this.

Comment: You can also create own controller for handling logins/logouts/registrations.

Answer (score 1):

Add these to your user model

---

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this

```
 $token = $user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.